# Cannot understand error when url is changed in django. It throws '404'

Tags: django

When I first created the urls with 'pk' they worked fine.
But when I use 'slug' for lookup, when I change the url it throws 404.

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import (ProductListView, ProductDetailView,
                    ProductFeaturedListView, ProductFeaturedDetailView)


app_name = 'products'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ProductListView.as_view(),
         name='list'),

    path('detail/<str:slug>/', ProductDetailView.as_view(),
         name='detail'),

    path('featured/', ProductFeaturedListView.as_view(),
         name='featured-list'),

    path('featured/<str:slug>/', ProductFeaturedDetailView.as_view(),
         name='featured-detail')
]
```

Now when I change the 'product-detail' url, the feature url throws error which is irrelevant. And it says that this particular view is causing it. But the view has no relation with 'featured-product-list' url.

```
from .views import (ProductListView, ProductDetailView,
                    ProductFeaturedListView, ProductFeaturedDetailView)


app_name = 'products'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ProductListView.as_view(),
         name='list'),

    path('<str:slug>/', ProductDetailView.as_view(),
         name='detail'),

    path('featured/', ProductFeaturedListView.as_view(),
         name='featured-list'),

    path('featured/<str:slug>/', ProductFeaturedDetailView.as_view(),
         name='featured-detail')
]
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCKY4.png)

On diagnosing it I find that it is trying to pass 'featured' as a slug, which is out of my logic.
Please help me to find what is causing this issue.

[here is the detailed error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vcWE.png)

```
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'products/product_detail.html'

    def get_object(self):
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
        try:
            instance = Product.objects.all().get(slug=slug)
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404('Not Found...')
        except Exception:
            raise Http404('huh?')
        return instance
```

Comment: Please include code (text), not *images* of code: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: 404 error means you are not getting the page at the given URL... !